# LightBlue on OS X 10.8: method signature mismatch

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth, lightblue

I'm using Nickolay Yegorov's [port of LightBlue for OS X 10.8](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4). Immediately upon importing the `lightblue` module, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commander.py", line 3, in <module>
    import lightblue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from _lightblue import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_lightblue.py", line 397, in <module>
    class _AsyncDeviceInquiry(Foundation.NSObject):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    class _AsyncDeviceInquiry does not correctly implement protocol IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate: the signature for method deviceInquiryComplete:error:aborted: is v@:@iB instead of v@:@iZ
```

It seems like there might be a version mismatch. Is there a known fix for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the file `src/mac/_lightblue.py` in the source from [Yegorov's repo](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4). Find line 467 (looks like the following):

```
deviceInquiryComplete_error_aborted_ = objc.selector(
    deviceInquiryComplete_error_aborted_, signature="v@:@iB")
```

Change the string `v@:@iB` to `v@:@iZ`. Reinstall LightBlue from this source:

```
cd <lightblue_root> && sudo python setup.py install
```

This should solve the signature error.

### Binary

[dlamblin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459/dlamblin) requested a binary with this fix. Here is [my `LightAquaBlue.framework`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7338/LightAquaBlue.framework.zip), built for OS X 10.8.2 with Python 2.7.4 (put in `/Library/Frameworks`).

Comment: I think the line-number is wrong (you might have been looking at the column number?). The line in question is 467. Thanks for figuring this out though!

Comment: Doh! Thanks for catching that :)

Comment: I'd love it if someone could just contribute the built binary for 10.8 to a fork of the github project for this. For those of us without XCode and uninterested playing with the project in the ide. `LightAquaBlue framework, found at /Library/Frameworks/LightAquaBlue.framework`

Comment: Added a link to my `LightAquaBlue.framework` — hopefully it works on your end.